# Create second button and reload form page

Tags: hooks

I have a form with Entity Registration module. 
I have to add another button in order to save and add another account to registration. 
For this i created a second module and i try to overide the first module. I created a hook :

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id)  {  
    // add second button
    if($form_id=='registration_form'){
        $form['actions']['save_reload'] = array(
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => t('Save and add'),
            '#weight' => 0,
        );
        $form['actions']['#save_reload'][] = 'mymodule_node_form_submit';
    }
}
function mymodule_node_form_submit ($form, &$form_state) {
    drupal_set_message('Test Submit');
    $form_state['redirect'] === FALSE;
}
```

Unfortunatelly it doesn't reload after the form is sent.

Comment: Did you try `$form_state['rebuild'] === TRUE` ?

Comment: maybe just `=` instead of `===`?